# blockChainDownloadLocked ignoring the duplicate request error

Tags: bitcoinj, java

I work with a bitcoin wallet app using the `Java/BitcoinJ`. The app has custom features such as showing balance, transactions, address and sending option. It was running fine and suddenly, I get the `blockChainDownloadLocked ignoring the duplicate request` error in the app.

```
org.bitcoinj.core.Peer: 06/19/2017 16:26:28 - blockChainDownloadLocked(00000000b873e79784647a6c82962c70d228557d24a747ea4d1b8bbe878e1206): ignoring duplicated request: 00000000076d710f40120e2f6693371bf6a7c4a9d149fb665664272a91dccf5a
org.bitcoinj.core.Peer: 06/19/2017 16:26:28 - java.lang.Throwable
    at org.bitcoinj.core.Peer.blockChainDownloadLocked(Peer.java:1446)
    at org.bitcoinj.core.Peer.processInv(Peer.java:1247)
    at org.bitcoinj.core.Peer.processMessage(Peer.java:489)
    at org.bitcoinj.core.PeerSocketHandler.receiveBytes(PeerSocketHandler.java:182)
    at org.bitcoinj.net.BlockingClient.runReadLoop(BlockingClient.java:122)
    at org.bitcoinj.net.BlockingClient$1.run(BlockingClient.java:81)
```

I use `IntellIJ` and cleared the Cache `(Invalidate Cache/ Restart ...)` and deleted the `target` folder to resolve it. It didn't help. Later, on enter in the `Cache` folder in the `Mac OS` and deleted everything inside all the folders.

I think rolling back the entire blockchain would be a solution, but, open for better suggestions.

What's the issue here and how to solve?

Comment: Are you using PeerGroup or just one Peer? If just one Peer, is it your own node?

Comment: How do I suppose to know that?

Comment: I assume its `PeerGroup`

Comment: If you're using PeerGroup then it connects to multiple peers simultaneously and will switch to another download peer if one is stuck downloading. I've seen the above problem too but usually it simply recovers by switching peers.

btw. You should know the code you're using.

Comment: Its repeating again and again for me. I can connect with main net btw. How to solve this issue?